# Have more than one active module in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, angular2-routing

Angular 2 final has been released and I've been playing around with the final router release.

A good example of the router in action can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/mXSjnUtN7CM6ZqtOicE2?p=preview

I was wondering if there's any mechanism for keeping the current module rendered in the DOM (but hidden) while loading in a new one on top? The use case here is that perhaps a user may be using an Admin-type module and realise they need to create some asset (perhaps a user) so jump to a Users module to create; before hopping back to where they were in the Admin module.

In this scenario, the user could be at some deep-linked section of the Admin module and it would be very strange behaviour for them to lose what they were doing.

Is this possible? From all I've done so far, I've seen that the modules presented in the `<router-outlet>` tags get dumped off the DOM completely.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently components added by the router are discarded when the route is changed. [This is planned to be made configurable eventually](http://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7757#issuecomment-23673784%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B6).

If you keep data (model) in shared services (that are **not** discarded) instead of the component itself, then the user gets back the original view when navigating back to a previous route.

The services needs to be provided on a component that isn't removed by the router. The root component or providers in an `@NgModule()` that is not lazy-loaded would work.

Comment: Keeping the data cached in the services is only a partial salve for this kind of problem though... If the user is at a deep-linked area, or has some complex configuration, that can't really be cached in services. Do you have any links to documents that say this is planned to be configurable? I'd like to see that :)

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7757#issuecomment-236737846
I can't imagine why a service would not be able to hold a reference to some data that a component would be able to.

Comment: I'm thinking more along the lines of switching between NgModules rather than just hopping between components. The idea is that I could have a module->component->component->component scenario where the user has to input some data, then hops to another module area. Thanks for that link though

Comment: NgModules don't have much meaning except being loaded as an unit when being lazy loaded, therefore I can't make much sense of using NgModules in this context. It's always components the router adds/removes when navigating.

Comment: I'm using them as feature-areas of an app, allowing me to lazy-load parts of the app / restrict access to the area when the user has no rights. I had actually thought using modules like this would be a typical approach to larger applications...

Comment: They might evolve into this, but they were added very recently and only as a means to make lazy loading work with the router.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate you hashing this out :)